# Hibernate ManyToMany and SINGLE_TABLE inheritance?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I want to make ManyToMany relationship ratio in one table. Is this possible?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "external_offer")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "offer_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class ExternalOffer

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    ......
```

K-Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "k")
public class K
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "K2GlobalOffer",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "k_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "global_offer_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<GlobalExternalOffer> globalExternalOffers;
```

EOffer-Entity

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("GLOBAL")
public class GlobalExternalOffer extends ExternalOffer
{

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "globalExternalOffers", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<K> kRef;
```

I receive here error. Do not understand why. This error I get only when there is ManyToMany. OneToMany relationship - works without problems.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
    ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.BagType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.EntityType
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.addPropertyPath(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initOrdinaryPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2300)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2347)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postConstruct(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3906)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:437)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 87 common frames omitted
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I took the code you posted and it works for me. Which version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: Really?
I'm using hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final from spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.0-RELEASE

Comment: Yes please check it out here https://github.com/simasch/jpa

Comment: yes, it's works. It's strange why I get an error. I thought maybe because I'm using liquibase. I disabled it, but the same error occurs.

Comment: are you sure that it's in this code?

Comment: This is only part of the project. Probably the error happens because of something else .. The main thing is that I understand that the associations are correct. Thank you. You really helped.